# Node.js Add-on with GYP "exceptions"

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8

I'm trying to make a C++ library to a node.js add-on.

Problem is on build time it errors like:

> error: no member named 'runtime_error' in namespace
>         'std'
>           throw std::runtime_error

Is there something I can replace runtime_error with to get rid of this errors? I tried to disable it with:

```
'cflags!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
'cflags_cc!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
```

But no luck

---

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/17). And it seems like I have the same question as the guy at the bottom but he didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I've done in some of my addons (e.g. [sipster](https://github.com/mscdex/sipster/blob/2fdbed818b3af9e4deb2d8b1763954b204f7b073/binding.gyp)) was just add the flag instead of trying to negate it:

```
'cflags_cc': [ '-fexceptions' ],
```

That works for me with at least node v0.10.x.

Comment: I did add the flag, but I'm getting that error stated above.

Comment: Are you testing on OSX or ?

Comment: You mean you've also added [this](https://github.com/mscdex/sipster/blob/2fdbed818b3af9e4deb2d8b1763954b204f7b073/binding.gyp#L20-L26) to your binding.gyp and you still get the error?

Comment: Also moved to an ubuntu machine, same thing.

Comment: Anyways, Did you use any references on building sipster? Would be great if you'd share :D

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS': 'YES',
```

to your xcode_settings, that did it for me.

Hope it helps.